# Custom trapezoidal function in matlab

Tags: matlab, waveform

I want to create a trapezoidal-like function in Matlab that will repeat not only for one or two periods, but for the duration of the simulation. Also, I want to control every value of the basic pulse, like the maximum value (in the picture attached it is 10000), how quickly it rises to maximum, how long it stays at maximum, and at zero. I have attached a picture of the main pulse. I have previously used a trigonometric function

```
Fn=((a/pi)*(asin(sin((2*pi/m)*t+l))+acos(cos((2*pi/m)*t+l)))-a/2+c)
```

but I cannot control all the above characteristics and therefore its not representative of what i want to do.

[Picture of what I have currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKqvI.jpg)

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly as follows? You want a function f(t) with the graph show in the image, with custom times and height of the pulse.

If not please clarify your question. I get confused by your reference to a trigonometric function, which doesn't look like the image.

Comment: Is that acceptable? http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJtYXgobWluKDAuNyxhYnMoc2luKHgpKSksMC4yKSoyIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwLCJzaXplIjpbNjQ5LDM5OV19XQ--

Comment: Thanks for responding.Yes i want a function f(t) (if it is possible) for the graph that i have in the image.In the image of course is only one period and i want it to repeat it self for the whole simulation time.The one that you have post is pretty much like the Fn trigonometric function that i have above.What i want though is lets say a left side trapezoidal wave like in the image i have posted.

Comment: There are definitely two ways to solve this issue or by some trigonometric function (f(t)) like the one above or by means of writing a few lines like a for loop.I have written something in matlab but its not exactly what i want, i can't get the ''pause'' part after the drop to zero if you know what i mean.t = linspace(0,50,1000)
Fmax = 10000
ts1 = 2;
ts2 = 5;
n = max(size(t));
for i = 1:n
    A = floor(t(i)/ts2);
    if t(i) < (A)*ts2+ts1
        Fn(i) = Fmax.*(1-(t(i)-A*ts2)/ts1);
       elseif t>= (A*ts2)+ts1 
        Fn(i) = 1e-20;
     
    end
end

Fclamp=-Fn+Fmax+2*1e-20;

plot(t,Fclamp)

Comment: Thanks guys i have solved this problem.